building gvim from source
I am in fedora-41 beta, and getting error in running gvim as:
:py3 import sys; print(sys.version) 
E448: Could not load library function _PyObject_NextNotImplemented

This is by turn, making vim unusable if ultisnips is loaded.
I am trying to compile [g]vim from source using:
./configure --with-features=huge --enable-python3interp  --enable-gui=auto --prefix=/tmp 

which is building vim, vut not gvim or vim -g.
Can someone tell me how to compile gvim from source? I am using vim from the git: git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git

Try to add --enable-gui=gtk or similar, see vim/src/INSTALL (https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/e6b01cfe01a2722ec55a011ae04c4c404e88f924/src/INSTALL#L128) for more instructions on enabling the GUI

BTW instead of building from source you could look into why :py3 is not working in your gvim provided by Fedora, this really shouldn't happen with a distro package, not sure why you're running into that

Did you happen to mess up with the Python install from your Fedora? As in, overwrite it with a Python built from source? That's probably not a great idea, if you need a newer Python you might want to install it to a different location, definitely not overwrite the system Python, which many components in your system will depend on

Its in beta... In fedora I have confirmed that this is the case. Probably because vim is compiled with py3. 12 but in fedora, the version has changed to python3. 13

try to build with stable ABI instead. Also there is this issue with python3.13 and Vim currently: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/15534
